# WireShark Log - On a TCP/IP connection between two hosts, multiple [FIN, ACK] and [ACK] responses, then eventual [RST, ACK] flags in response. Why?

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection, ip, wireshark

Communications between two hosts are established using a socket connection, and 10.12.10.1 is able to send data to 10.10.12.217 every second.

[image: Communications Established]

For some unknown reason, .217 starts sending [FIN, ACK] flags.

[image]

After many [FIN, ACK] flags, .1 starts responding with [RST, ACK] flags.

[image]

I'm at a bit of a loss - communications seem to work fine until .217 starts with the [FIN, ACK] flags. I'm also not sure why .1 responds with [RST, ACK] after a while. Any ideas or insight into what the issue could be or what host is causing the trouble? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ACK which is the flag and corresponding sequence number. Are present in almost all TCP packets. However, there are two exceptions. The clients SYN packet due to the fact that it hasn’t had anything to ACK yet and the client’s RST packet where the server just hasn’t responded yet to the clients SYN packet. The reason for that would be that the session has not been established yet.

```
We have to come to the understanding that Data reception does not always work packet to packet. Nor does it work in message to message like in older, point-to-point protocols. Where you would not send the next message until you have received the ACK for the last one that was initially sent. The reason that it does not wait any longer for the ACK is because it would essentially slow down the actual transfer between the trip and the path around the network and it would elapse between any of the two messages initially  sent.

So, there is really no requirement as to when the client sends the first FIN flag. Either side wether it is the client of the server can send it whenever they want to signal. Therefore it does it’s own thing in retrospect and can choose whether or not to send data on its own time even if the other side hasn’t or has sent a an ACK for N+1 flag with the payload. 

In retrospect when your looking at an ACK + FIN ( you should always see 2 FINs  and 2ACKS belonging to the FINs. Sometimes you will even see FIN -ACK -RST, where one side closes the connection with a rather harsh reset flag. So when your looking at the FIN – ACK responses if you have not seen the RST flag then it means technically that the connection is still open. 

When you send your own ACK sequence to inform a remote server and or router or party about the payload octet you received without a gap in the data the TCP stack receives a packet with the FIN flag set with a payload whose last octet sequence number is N. It sends and ACK for N+1. It can send it either by itself in the same packet or it can send its own FIN flag. It really depends on that situation at hand. So, if the remote has not received a payload during the time it sends three packets. ACK sequence number in all three of these packets are the same but, they are always there. 

You have to pay attention to the fact that FIN flags are often piggy-backed by data packets. This makes them very easy to overlook. You should really take the time to actually “ISOLATE your TCP connection” first. Then you can search for the FIN flagged packets with the connection to see if there were actually two FINs.

The reason you are getting this problem is for the fact that the TCP connection is not really a 3-way hand shake but rather a 2-way hand shake. There really is no actual order in which device sends and initiates the closing of a session by sending the FIN packet. It can get into the FIN-WAIT1 and then when FIN-WAIT1 is in wait position the other device is expecting to send the FIN after it gets into the  FIN-WAIT2 state. Then really it just either continues or does not because it has in some cases a connection that can be resumed by another application and or device that may be using the connection so ti will just send the FIN and then it will wat till it gets the ACK for them. The thing here is that both devices have to actually accept the FIN and the ACK to terminate the connection. So if something is still using the connection such as the piggy-backed data I mentioned earlier, then it will just ignore the ACK to terminate and remain open. The only time that it actually terminates the session is when both sides agree on the termination. That is the reason you are seeing that many packets. Because its not a four-way handshake but in retrospect it is really a 2-way hand-shake. 

What you really are seeing here, and getting confused by; is the fact that you are seeing the ACK and then you are seeing that FIN is acknowledging the last byte it received. If there is a problem and or an issue then you have to go back to troubleshooting and find out where the data is still open and or being used, and why it isn’t doing that. In retrospect you can check the Acknowledgment number to make sure that they have acknowledged each-other.


1. RST Packet: When a server receives a client’s SYN packet but cannot establish a connection or some reason it is because the server is unavailable and or the port is closed. It responds with an RST(reset) packet. This packet indications that the connection request is rejected and it allows the client to attempt a connection with another server.
2. Date Reception: In TCP, data reception does not strictly occur on a packet-to-packet basis. The receiver can buffer the process data at it’s own pace, even if it hasn’t sent an ACK for every received packet. This approach avoids unnecessary delays caused by waiting for individual ACK’s for each packet and improves overall network efficiency.
3. FIN packet: The FIN flag is used to initiate the termination of a TCP connection. Either the client or the server can send the FIN packet whenever they wish to signal the end of data transmission. The FIN packet indicates that the sender has no more data to send.  The other side acknowledges the FIN with the ACK packet, and the connection moves through several states (e.g., FIN-WAIT1, FIN-WAIT2, TIME-WAIT) before it is fully closed.
4. Multiple FINs and ACKs: to properly terminate a TCP connection, both sides must agree on the termination. It involves a series of FIN and ACK exchanges. The FIN-ACK-RST scenario is possible when one side forcefully terminates the Connection using a reset (RST) flag without waiting for the proper termination handshake.
5. Piggybacking FIN: It is important to note that FIN flags can be included in packets carrying data. This means that the FIN flag can be easily overlooked if not specifically searched for in the context of a TCP connection. Isolation he TCP connection and then looking for FIN-flagged packets within that connection can help identify and or terminate the process.
6. Troubleshooting: if you ever encounter problems with the termination process or observe unexpected packet behavior, it is essential to troubleshoot and identify any open or active data connections that might be the culprit of preventing the termination. Checking the Acknowledgment numbers can help you ensure that both sides have properly acknowledge each others packets.

With this being said. Remember that while the general TCP flow follows a 3-way handshake for connection to be established and a 4-way handshake for the termination, the actual behavior can and will always vary to the specific implementation and the current network conditions. It is very important to refer to the TCP specifications and consider any relevant factors when coming into a situation like your specific scenario. 

   I hope this help’s you better understand what is going on here. 
                          Respectfully, 
                             ~SIN~
```

Comment: Instead of pasting large amounts of text, please link to it instead.